# Angular4 Component Flag state not updating to html ng if condition

Tags: javascript, angular

I have developed a Login component and html . The user login checks happens in an API via LoginService  and if the Service response Status code is 200 , the page navigates to Dashboard else it should display Bad UserName.

The Login Component Code is as follows

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-login',
    templateUrl: './login.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],
    providers: [LoginService]
})

export class LoginComponent {
    @Input() username: string;
    @Input() password: string;
    loginSuceed: boolean;
    errorMessage: string;
    title: string;
    payLoad = new LoginPayLoad();
    response = 0;
    constructor(private router: Router, private service: LoginService) {
        this.loginSuceed = true;
        this.errorMessage = 'Bad UserName / Password';
        this.title = 'Database Documentation Management';
    }

    onSubmit(f: NgForm) {

        if (f.valid) {
            this.payLoad.username = this.username;
            this.payLoad.password = this.password;
            console.log(this.payLoad);
            this.service.postLogin(this.payLoad)
                .subscribe((res) => {
                    if (res === 200) {
                        console.log('Enterd here');
                        this.loginSuceed = true;
                        this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
                    } else {
                        this.loginSuceed = false;
                    }
                })

        }

    }
}
```

Follows the HTML code ,

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-12">

        <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="!loginSuceed" >
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            {{ errorMessage }}
        </div>


        <form class="login" #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username">User Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username"  [(ngModel)]="username" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="password" [(ngModel)]="password" required>
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" [disabled]="!f.valid">Submit</button>

        </form>
    </div>


</div>
```

When Status code is not 200 **this.loginsucceed** is set as false .But the ngIf alert message doesnt triggers.  WHY ? 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

For further reference , the LoginService looks like ,

```
export class LoginService {
    private _url = 'http://localhost:8080/login';
    header = new Headers({ 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' });
    options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.header });
    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    postLogin(payLoad: LoginPayLoad) {
        return this.http.post(this._url, JSON.stringify(payLoad), this.options)
            .map(res => res.status);

    }

}
```

Comment: what does your postLogin method look like in the service?

Comment: OP, I tried to reproduce this with a stub LoginService and I couldn't.  The problem is probably there.  Are you absolutely sure that `loginSuceed` is actually being set to false (logged it in the console or something)?

Comment: @JosiahKeller Yes I logged it,and it enters inside else block

Comment: @AthavanKanapuli OK, and does the alert div appear in the inspector at all?

Comment: @JosiahKeller Nope It doesnt appear in the inspector. So its clear the loginsuceed value is not update hence ngif removed it from the DOM. Correct me if am wrong

Comment: @AthavanKanapuli Correct, if the value is set to false, then the ngIf condition should become true and it should be displayed.  Just trying to make sure I'm not missing something.

Comment: @JosiahKeller  Or should I emit the LoginSucceed value using an output variable EventEmitter? Will that help?

Comment: @AthavanKanapuli No, that shouldn't be necessary.  Have you tried using an error callback (2nd parameter to `subscribe()`) to catch the non-200 codes?

Comment: Are you using `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` for any components that are parents of your `LoginComponent`?